# Create Redis database with composite key using Python

Tags: python, redis

**Goal**: make a table with composite with Redis database.

I have data stored in JSON in this format:

```
{
        "customer_id" : "C001",
        "order_id" : "O789",
        "product_code": "P007",
        "quantity": 1000,
}
```

My composite key would be customer_id and product_code. I tried to implement this in Redis-CLI with this [Composite Primary Key equivalent in Redis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43721998/composite-primary-key-equivalent-in-redis)

However, I am a bit lost how to use this in Python. Should I use ZADD() or something else?

Answer (score 0):

ZADD is used to add an entry (score/member) to a sorted set. You dont want to use a sorted set because there are no common score among productcode / quantity. You could use one if for example you wanted to store all orders of a client, storing orderid and their timestamps, making it easier to retrieve.

I think you should use a hash, this data structure is nice to hold keys/values inside a key. You could do :

```
HMSET C001:O789 product_code P007 quantity 1000
```

And get them :

```
HGET C001:O789 product_code //p007
HGET C001:O789 quantity //1000
HGETALL C001:O789 // p007, 1000
```